# how to convert to array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this string which I want to convert to an array:

```
var test = "{href:'one'},{href:'two'}";
```

So how can I convert this to an array?:

```
var new = [{href:'one'},{href:'two'}];
```

Comment: You should change the string to be valid JSON.

Comment: Where do you get that string? You can surround it in `[]` (by concatenation) then `JSON.parse()` it if you're sure the rest is properly formed. ( it isn't though, as the properties `href` are not quoted)

Comment: You would need to do something like this.. `JSON.parse('[' + '{"href":"one"},{"href":"two"}' + ']')` But why not construct it properly at the start itself rather than postprocessing some invalid JSON.

Comment: also `new` is a keyword and cannot be used as the name of a variable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you got it from..

If possible you should correct it a bit to make it valid JSON syntax (*at least in terms of the quotes*)

```
var test  = '{"href":"one"},{"href":"two"}';
var arr = JSON.parse('[' + test + ']');
```

Notice the `"` around both keys and values.

(*making directly `var test  = '[{"href":"one"},{"href":"two"}]';` is even better*)

Comment: If it could be modified to be a bit more like JSON, hopefully it could be modified to _be JSON_ and be an array to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski of'course :) i am just being easy on the OP

Answer (score 1):

If you could modify the original string to be valid JSON then you could do this:

```
JSON.parse(test)
```

Valid JSON:

```
var test  = '[{"href":"one"},{"href":"two"}]';
```

Answer (score 1):

If changing the string to be valid JSON is not an option, **and you fully trust this string, and its origin** then I would use eval:

```
var test = "{href:'one'},{href:'two'}";
var arr = eval("[" + test + "]");
```

On that last note, please be aware that, if this string is coming from the user, it would be possible for them to pass in malicious code that `eval` will happily execute.

As an extremely trivial example, consider this

```
var test = "(function(){ window.jQuery = undefined; })()";
var arr = eval("[" + test + "]");
```

Bam, jQuery is wiped out.

Demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J3SaH/)

Comment: But be careful about where the input is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}';
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + str + ']');
```

jsonObj is your JSON object.

Comment: no need for jQuery. The JSON is natively supported in all browsers nowadays.. http://caniuse.com/json